# Safe and efficient way to use String and its pointer in different collections

Tags: rust

- I have a bunch of long immutable strings, which I would like to store in a `HashSet`.
- I need a bunch of mappings with these strings as keys.
- I would like to use references to these strings as keys in these mappings to avoid copying strings.

This is how I managed to eventually get to this status. The only concern is this extra copy I need to make at line 5.

```
let mut strings: HashSet<String> = HashSet::new();  // 1
let mut map: HashMap<&String, u8> = HashMap::new(); // 2
                                                    // 3
let s = "very long string".to_string();             // 4
strings.insert(s.clone());                          // 5
let s_ref = strings.get(&s).unwrap();               // 6
map.insert(s_ref, 5);                               // 7
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=93470c0f11eba8e042ef6e474d622b39&version=stable&backtrace=0)

To avoid this cloning I found two workarounds:

- Use `Rc` for string (adds overhead and [code clutter](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9f43458bac3d0f27332ffd3fc6e3d379&version=stable&backtrace=0))
- Use [unsafe code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fd34caa9373c3f8517eab7ec76a7aad8&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Is there any sensible way to remove this excessive cloning?

Comment: Keep in mind that the HashMap may reorganize its internals when it is modified, moving the items around and making the `&String` references dangling.

Comment: Why not just keep the `HashMap`? You could still check a string's membership with the HashMap

Comment: kennytm, I need several mappings and so didn't want to copy keys for every one. I can have one hashmap with just strings and then others with references to them. this is the main problem.

Comment: What about a `HashMap<String, Content>` where `Content` is a struct of values for your several mappings?

Comment: That is one way to solve this but it has different semantics, for example I will not be able to get some mappings as immutable and others as mutable and separate which data gets accessed in which functions

Comment: What about using `&str` instead of `String`? You could easily have a `HashSet<&str>` and `HashMap<&str, u8>`.

Comment: @antoyo: same issue, you have to handle the lifetime of those `str` (especially if created dynamically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that what you are looking for is String Interning. There is a library, [string-cache](https://github.com/servo/string-cache), which was developed as part of the Servo project which may be of help.

In any case, the basics are simple:

- a long-lived pool of `String`, which guarantees they will not be moving at all
- a look-up system to avoid inserting duplicates in the pool

You can use a [typed arena](https://crates.io/crates/typed-arena) to store your `String`, and then store `&str` to those strings without copying them (they will live for as long as the arena lives). Use a `HashSet<&str>` on top to avoid duplicates, and you're set.