# Does Rust's String::from("literal") copy all the string data?

Tags: performance, rust

I notice that I constantly need to do `String::from("mydummystring")` in Rust. Does the call to `from()` end up creating a full copy of the string data? Seems that would be a major performance issue.

Comment: Yes, it does, but you don't need to use an owned String if you don't need to mutate it. And if you do need to mutate it, you'd have to copy it out of .data segment as it will be marked read-only by the OS.

Comment: Something to keep in mind is Rust makes you very aware of when you're copying. In other words, "would be a major performance issue" compared to _what_? E.g. in C++ `void foo(const std::string&); foo("asd")` is gonna allocate and copy a string completely implicitly. Only recently did C++ even get a standard way to talk about non-owned strings in a...reasonable way (that's being generous).

Comment: The truly expensive operation is the heap application. It's among the most costly things we frequently do. The copy, while it may appear redundant is cheap in comparison, several orders in magnitude faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `From<&str>` for `String` works by creating a new heap-allocated buffer and copying the data from the original slice into it.

> Seems that would be a major performance issue.

Less than you'd think, probably. Copying a chunk of bytes is usually very fast. You should benchmark your code to know if copying is a bottleneck. Even when copying is slow, most non-trivial programs probably do *some* copying of strings; you can't just never copy anything.

Nevertheless, if there is a lot of *unnecessary* copying going on and it is a problem for your design, Rust offers plenty of other options. `String` is not Rust's only string type, or even the most frequently used one; if you don't need to copy strings, you can often borrow them using `&str`, share ownership using [`Rc<str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html), defer the owning decision to runtime using [`Cow<str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html), or even use a string interning library such as [`string-cache`](https://github.com/servo/string-cache). Ownership and copying of values is under *your* control with Rust, much more so than with most other languages, in fact. Ultimately, it's up to you to choose what kind of ownership makes the most sense for strings in your program.

#### References

- [What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24158114/3650362)
- [Storing UTF-8 Encoded Text with Strings](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch08-02-strings.html) (TRPL chapter 8.2)
- [Safe and efficient way to use String and its pointer in different collections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39205905/3650362)